# Run test from gradle in android

Tags: android, build.gradle, junit4, robolectric

I checked the similar question ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927627/android-gradle-how-to-build-application-and-run-tests-from-test-application), [sample gradle build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557946/writing-gradle-script-to-run-unit-test-cases-for-eclipse-android-test-project) ). but that solution did not worked for me.
I want to run junits using gradle file, for android eclipse project. Structure of Source project is below:

```
Application:
   -src
   -test
```

Structure of Test project:

```
TestProject:
- test (linked to test folder in source project)
```

Gradle file of source project is:

```
dependencies{
   compile project (':lib_project')
}
android{
   sourceSets{
       main{
       }
       test{
           java{
               srcDirs = ['test/com/project/testsuites']                    
           }
       }
       androidTest.setRoot('tests')
   }
}
```

Please suggest the updatations/changes need to implemented in gradle file.

Comment: if you run `./gradlew test` then do you see tests running?

Comment: @EugenMartynov i run command: 'gradle test' , but i'm getting Unexpected Top level exception: DexIndexOverFlowExepction: method id not found in [0, 0xffff]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l